# Reverse jquery resize shift functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you resize a div using jquery resize plugin, if  you hold the shift key the aspect ratio is kept.

Well it is possible to {aspectRatio: true} to option list and if i hold the shift key to disable the aspect ratio ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific on which plugin your using? A link to docs, maybe?

Comment: Sure. http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i managed by modifying the widget:

replaced

```
if (this._aspectRatio || b.shiftKey)
```

with

```
if (this._aspectRatio && !b.shiftKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey-patch the jquery resizable code for that without touching the source file, so you could still use its CDN.

```
var mouseDrag = $.ui.resizable.prototype._mouseDrag;
$.ui.resizable.prototype._mouseDrag = function (event) {
    event.shiftKey = !event.shiftKey;
    var aspectRatio = this._aspectRatio;
    this._aspectRatio = aspectRatio && event.shiftKey;
    mouseDrag.apply(this, arguments);
    this._aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
};
```